# Перенос локального приложения Laravel на хостинг

Tags: php, laravel

**Как мне перенести локальное приложение Laravel на хостинг, но потом как-то применять миграцию в БД?**

> Хостинг: gpdhost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Закомитьте, отправьте на гит репозиторий.
После в хостинге по ssh клонируйте свой проект, выполните composer install, создайте .env файл для продакшана.
После по ssh доступу выполняйте артисан команды.

Answer (score 0):

Если там есть ssh, входите, вводите команды как на локалке.